# Asking user to contact you

Tags: discussion, support

If a user is not getting the answers he needs, could I ask him to send me an email or something or pm me in skype?

Comment: no, this is directly against SO protocol. Jeff Atwood himself said multiple times, he doesnt want stack to morph in FB. but *if* you want, you can put contact info in profile

Comment: How so @Adel? If the author of an answer is willing to take things off-site because they cannot be dealt with within the scope of the site, that's up to him, isn't it? Not saying it's advisable, but still ...

Comment: What would this provide that an answer wouldn't? Or if really nessisary a chat session

Comment: @Bart - Ok touche, I misunderstood this.  Ok , true

Comment: @VBA , you can comment anything you want.. but it's maybe not so wise. I havent seen people really share emails directly.  they may turn into vampires that send too much

Comment: Ok I'm getting different answers here. Adel is saying its against protocol but Bart is saying its up to you??!!

Comment: @VBAProgrammer It's strongly discouraged and against the general community's values, however it's not strictly a violation of the rules (in the sense that you could be punished in some way) nor is anyone actually capable of stopping you if you're suitably motivated.  So you *can*, but you really *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not generally encouraged, but there's nothing we can do to stop you from doing that. You do have to realize, though, that we can't be responsible for anything that might come of you intentionally publishing your email or chat usernames. Moderators will generally delete any comments they run across containing private information like this simply to prevent users from spamming your email or other malicious behavior - because we're nice like that and people tend not to think about the long-term in the heat of the conversation.

The only thing we really ask is that if you two *do* go elsewhere to figure out the final solution, you come back and add the answer so that others experiencing the same issue can see the solution - even if you use the on-site chat feature to discuss the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If the scope of an answer does not provide you with adequate means to help the OP out, you can always take it to chat. Provided of course that the both of you have sufficient rep.

Are you allowed to help the OP out via e-mail or Skype or whatever? Nobody is going to stop you. I wouldn't advice it (nasty help-vampire situations can happen pretty quickly) but it's entirely up to you.

Should you however do this, then I would kindly request that you do finish the Q&A on site. Once you have established what the problem is, and how to resolve it, both be so kind to finish the question, and leave an appropriate answer.